# Итеративное умножение матриц с разбиением на на блоки

Tags: c, алгоритм, матрицы, кэширование, умножение

Я хотел написать умножение матриц с учётом кэша. Нашёл алгоритм на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0)
Алгоритм:

```
Ввод: матрица A(n x m) и B(m x p)
Пусть С будет новой матрицей (n x p)
Выбираем часть размера T = Θ( sqrt(M) )
int I,J,K,i,j,k,sum;
for(I = 1; I <= n; I += T)
  for(J = 1; J <= p; J += T)
    for(K = 1; K <= m; K += T)
      for(i = I; i <= min(I + T, n); i++)
        for(j = J; j <= min(J + T, p); j++) {
          sum = 0;
          for(k = K; k <= min(K + T, m); k++)
            sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
          C[i][j] += sum;
        }
```

M - это вроде размер кэша, но мне совсем не понятна эта нотация с тетой от корня: T = Θ( sqrt(M) ). Как её вычеслить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у вас размер кеша 2 Мегабайта

```
$ lscpu

L3 cache:            2048K
```

Например матрица у вас будет с элементами типа `double`. У него размер 8 байт.

Тогда максимальный вариант размеров матрицы, влазящая в кеш будет `sqrt(2048 * 1024 / 8) == 512`. То-есть размер матрицы `sizeof(double[512][512])` равен размеру кеша.

О большое Θ - написали, потому, что неизвестно с каким типом вы будете работать.